# Where are the final missing eggs/gems in Spyro Year of the Dragon?

Tags: spyro-year-of-the-dragon, spyro-reignited-trilogy

I’ve just finished Spyro Year of the Dragon on the Reignited Trilogy and want to play the bonus mission, but I’m missing 3 eggs and 400 gems.

I have 100% in all levels and 111% in midnight mountains. I also have all the skill points if that matters. Anyone know where I’m missing the gems and eggs???

Comment: Levels only show in the guidebook if you've visited them: therefore it's likely you've missed a level or two. Check the Speedway levels in each homeworld (as they aren't required for story progression)

Answer (score 4):

Go through your guidebook. You’ve missed a world somewhere. In my case it was one of the speedway levels. 3 eggs and 400 gems missing.

Comment: Yeah figured it out as soon as I posted the question. I had missed Country Speedway (I think it’s called) from the 2nd world. All sorted now

Answer (score 4):

Try returning to the spots where there’s a sign of Sparx and Zoe is waiting asking for him. You’ll have to visit each overworld in order.

Answer (score 2):

Levels only show up in your guidebook once visited for the first time, so if all levels are showing as completed, it's likely you have simply missed a level. As for which - it is likely a Speedway or Sparx level, as these ones are not required for the main story progression.

Check your guidebook against the following level list. Ensure you've visited/completed them all:

#### Sunrise Spring

1. Sunny Villa
2. Cloud Spires
3. Molten Crater
4. Seashell Shore
5. Sheila's Alp

**Speedway**: Mushroom Speedway
**Boss**: Buzz's Dungeon

#### Midday Gardens

1. Icy Peak
2. Enchanted Towers
3. Spooky Swamp
4. Bamboo Terrace
5. Sgt. Byrd's Base

**Speedway**: Country Speedway
**Boss**: Spike's Arena

#### Evening Lake

1. Frozen Altars
2. Lost Fleet
3. Fireworks Factory
4. Charmed Ridge
5. Bentley's Outpost

**Speedway**: Honey Speedway
**Boss**: Scorch's Pit

#### Midnight Mountain

1. Crystal Islands
2. Desert Ruins
3. Haunted Tomb
4. Dino Mines
5. Agent 9's Lab

**Speedway**: Harbor Speedway
**Boss**: Sorceress's Lair

#### Sparx Levels

The requirements to unlock these levels are listed underneath the level name

1. Crawdad Farm
   <sub>Defeat Buzz</sub>
2. Spider Town
   <sub>Defeat Spike + complete Crawdad Farm</sub>
3. Starfish Reef
   <sub>Defeat Scorch + complete the two previous Sparx levels</sub>
4. Bugbot Factory
   <sub>Defeat Sorceress + complete all previous Sparx levels</sub>

#### Bonus Level

- Super Bonus Round (Must have 100% to access)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are missing a level like Robotnik suggested as well.

You can check if you are missing something in the [Fandom Wiki](https://spyro.fandom.com/wiki/Spyro:_Year_of_the_Dragon), since it lists all the levels in the Realm section.

Also note that if you have finished collecting everything you will unlock a special endgame Area.

The third Spyro had a Realm called [Super Bonus Round](https://spyro.fandom.com/wiki/Super_Bonus_Round).
Finishing everything in there will also grant you a few percentages, if I remember correctly.

To unlock it you need 149 Eggs and 15.000 gems, so indeed you are missing some levels.

Comment: Because checking the Wiki is always the best answer for any Gamequestion, doesn't matter if its DS, Binding of Isaac, Enter the Gungeon or Ark. If it got a Wiki page somewhere and it's well maintained and somewhat complete, you will usually find all your answers there. But still I am happy to help if anyone got a question. Some things you can't figure out with a wiki alone.