# I have a 100% on everything in Year of the Dragon (trilogy) but i am missing 9 eggs and 900 gems. Why?

Tags: spyro-reignited-trilogy, spyro-year-of-the-dragon

I have a 100% on everything in *Year of the Dragon* (trilogy) but I am missing 9 eggs and 900 gems. Why?

Comment: I believe the remaster retains the rather odd completion percentages of the original games, 120%, 100% and 117% for the games in order. This might be related to what you're seeing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are the final missing eggs/gems in Spyro Year of the Dragon?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/341298/where-are-the-final-missing-eggs-gems-in-spyro-year-of-the-dragon)

Answer (score 0):

A level will only appear in your guidebook if you actually entered it.

As the flight levels are not required for advancing the story, I would say that there is a good chance that you are missing some of them.

There should be the same number of realms in every homeworld.